# Create instance based on class ID

Tags: java, oop, enums

I am currently working on an application which uses packets each assigned their own ID. Every packet class is a sub-class of `BasePacket`. What I am trying to do is when a new packet is received I want to read the ID from the buffer and then create an instance of that certain packet's class to read and store all the data for later use.  My problem is I'm not sure how to go about creating an instance of the class based on the ID. My first thought was just an `Enum` that held the ID of the packet and reference to their class.

```
public enum Packets
{
    HANDSHAKE(0, HandshakePacket.class),
    HEARTBEAT(1, HeartbeatPacket.class),
    // etc
}
```

I would then call a get method with the packets ID.

```
public static BasePacket get(int id)
{
    for (Packets packet : Packets.values()) {
        if (packet.getId() == id) {
            return (BasePacket) packet;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

This worked rather well, but I'm still curious if there is possibly a better way to do this? One of my thoughts was to use the `Factory design` pattern but I'm unsure how to implement for something like this or if it's even needed.

Comment: Yes I agree with you. You may use factory design pattern. But still with this design pattern you can use the enum

Comment: I'd go with a `Map` rather than an `enum`. There is no point in doing a linear search for each ID, when it can be done in O(1).

Comment: And how did your code work, anyway? As I also commented in the answer, `packet` is of type `Packets` which doesn't inherit from `BasePacket`. I think you forgot a method call somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty much the way to go - you map a known identifier (such as your enum) to a class type, then construct the class. That *is* the factory design pattern. The simplest factory would just switch over the id and return new:

```
 static BasePacket get(int id)
 {
    switch (id) {
       case 0:
          return new HandshakePacket();
       case 1:
          return new HeartbeatPacket();
    }
 }
```

That, of course, requires you to add to the `switch` statement when a new `BasePacket` is created. If you don't want to do that, then you can (as in your example) move the mapping somewhere else (possibly loaded at runtime) and dynamically construct the object:

```
static BasePacket get(int id)
{
    Packets packetId = Packets.values()[id];
    Class packetClass = packetId.getPacketClass();
    object packetInstance = packetClass.newInstance();
    return (BasePacket)packetInstance;
}
```

Of course, if any of your `Packet` subclasses don't have a default constructor, this will fail. Once you get there, you'll probably want a dependency injection container to take care of wiring that up for you.